# Failed to connect to AWS instance in WinSCP. But works for PuTTY

Tags: putty, amazon-web-services

I am able to connect to AWS Linux 2023 instance using PuTTY.

When connecting using WinSCP site information, I'm getting error:

> Server refused our key. Authentication failed.

From WinSCP I can press <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> and it opens PuTTY properly. That indicates that connection info is valid.

How can I connect WinSCP to AWS server?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your server needs rsa-sha2. And you are using up-to-date version of PuTTY, which supports rsa-sha2, but an obsolete version of WinSCP. The [support for rsa-sha2](https://winscp.net/tracker/1952) was added in WinSCP 5.20.

Please update to the latest version of WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution. i have upgraded winscp. the problem got solved. now it is connected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Likely you needed rsa-sha2: https://winscp.net/tracker/1952